# How do I get my discord bot to send a random meme/picture

Tags: image, random, discord, discord.js, bots

How do I get my bot to send a random picture/meme in discord. I'm using discord.js and this is as far as I got.

```
  if (msg.content === '-meme');
  var randommeme = ({files:["https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/757397429107556422/757524795452686426/GBoat_Watermark.png"]} , {files:["https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/815040456244985947/816225078969892864/A_good_fluffy_goat.png"]});
  var fact = Math.floor(Math.random() * randommeme.length); 
  msg.channel.send('goat meme', randommeme[fact]);
});
```

This should send a random picture but when I run the command it only says "goat meme". I tried this code before and it worked.

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === '+meme') {
  msg.channel.send("This is a good fluffy goat", {files: ["https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/757397429107556422/816234172737126430/A_good_fluffy_goat.png","https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/757397429107556422/757524795452686426/GBoat_Watermark.png"]});
  }
});
```

I really don't know what Im doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create an array of links, and then use the random function to get a random link from the array.

```
const meme = ['link_1','link_2','link_3','link_4'];
const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * meme.length);
message.channel.send('Goat meme',{files:[meme[index]]});
```

where link_1, link_2 etc. are attachment file URL.

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in line two, the right code should be this:

```js
var randommeme = ({files:["https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/757397429107556422/757524795452686426/GBoat_Watermark.png", "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/815040456244985947/816225078969892864/A_good_fluffy_goat.png"]});
```